# Includeexpr + substitute not behaving as I would expect

Tags: substitute, path, include

I am using `includeexpr` and `substitute()` in a ftplugin to remove a portion of an include string for `gf` functionality (in twig template files, for the curious), but I get an error instead.

Twig includes look like this:

```
{% include "@mynamespace/footer/footer.twig" %}
```

I already have my `path` setup to include the twig template directory, and I want to remove the `@mynamespace/` piece to properly map to the filesystem.

I used this expression, adapted from the helpdocs example for Java.

```
setlocal includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'@mynamespace/','','')
```

However, when I try to `gf` an include, I get this error:

```
E447: Can't find file "mynamespace/footer/footer.twig" in path
```

I would have expected `substitute()` to remove the `@mynamespace/` piece. I looked at the documentation, and couldn't see anything I was doing wrong. I tried messing around with different invocations, using `\` to escape the `@` or `/`, but always got the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim is separating out the `@` when extracting the filename. Why? Per `:h gf`...

> [Vim] uses  the `'isfname'` option to find out which characters are supposed to be in a file name.

You can demonstrate this another way by putting your cursor on the filename and running

```
:echo expand('<cfile>')
```

The response is "mynamespace/footer/footer.twig". `<cfile>` is determined the same way as for `v:fname`. That means you can proceed with your substitution with the same assumption....

```
:setlocal includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'mynamespace/','','')
```

...and `gf` will look for `footer/footer.twig`.

Comment: Wow, I never would have figured that out, but such a simple solution. Thanks so much!

Comment: You bet. Happy to help. Cheers.